# "Automation Running Hold both volume buttons to stop", how to loose this grey transparent overlay message on iPhone screen while testing using Appium

Tags: ios, appium-ios, ios-ui-automation

I am testing an application on iPhone real device using appium.
I always see a grey transparent overlay message on the screen which sometimes interferes with the automation script execution. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Details:

iOS version used: **iOS 15.1**

Appium Server GUI: **1.22**

Appium inspector: **2021.9.2**

Xcode: **13.1**

Comment: I am facing this same issue. Were you able to figure out what the issues is? Or is it a behaviour of iOS 15.1?

Comment: Its just an overlay and won't interfere with the testing...

Comment: so no way to disable it or maybe moved it to the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that it's just an overlay and doesn't effect the automation script while running. You just have to increase the brightness to be able to see the screen clearly.